# Book about crustacean aliens and a ship wrecked teenager?

Tags: story-identification, aliens, novel

I remember a book I read in middle school back in 2001/2002 about a teenage crustacean alien and a teenage human girl who was the sole survivor of a shipwreck on the crustacean's planet. In the book they end up becoming friends and also forming a romantic attachment before the girl gets rescued (just in time, since the crustaceans nearly discovered her presence).

Does anyone have any idea what I'm talking about or did I totally make this up?

Comment: What kind of crustacean did the aliens resemble?

Comment: I think they were more crab-like- but they were bipedal.